# Cumulative Effect

Tags: maximum-likelihood, autoregressive

Let $X_t$ be a causal AR($p$) model. If we have $n$ observations of this time series and fit an AR($m$) model with $m\gt p$ to the data; that is

$$X_t = \phi_1 X_{t-1} + \cdots + \phi_m X_{t-m} + W_t,$$

the quantity $1/(1 - \phi_1 - \cdots - \phi_m)$ is called the *cumulative effect.* Is there any result on the asymptotic distribution of this statistic (when $\phi$'s are replaced by their MLEs) as well as its applications?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Note that dollar signs \$ are needed to delimit $\TeX$ markup, which I added for you.

Comment: Thanks, @whuber